# How can I create a front-end chatbot with a custom knowledge base utilizing the OpenAI API?

Tags: frontend, backend, chatbot, openai-api

After successfully constructing a chatbot with a personalized knowledge base using the OpenAI API in Google Colab, the subsequent objective is to incorporate this chatbot into my website's front end, allowing users to interact with it.

In light of this, I would like to inquire about the feasibility of integrating a chatbot with a custom knowledge base in the front end. If it is possible, could you kindly outline the necessary steps involved in accomplishing this task?